# How do I use a variable in my .rspec file

Tags: rspec, rspec3

I want to use an environment variable called `TEST_ENV_NUMBER` in my `.rspec` file.

I initially put this line in `.rspec`

```
--format json --out ./tmp/$(TEST_ENV_NUMBER).json
```

however,

the file that gets created is literally `$(TEST_ENV_NUMBER).json`

How do I get `--out` to actually evaluate and use `TEST_ENV_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ERB`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files#using-erb-in-<code>.rspec</code>) for that.

```
--format json --out <%= "./tmp/#{ENV[TEST_ENV_NUMBER]}.json" %>
```